# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_E \sin^n(x)dx$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $E$ Lebesgue measurable of finite measure. Compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_E\sin^n(x)dx.$$

I already have the solution, but I did differently, and I would like to know if it's correct or not.

We can see that $\sin^n(x)\longrightarrow 0$ pointwise.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By [Egoroff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem) there is a closed set $F\subset E$ s.t. $m(E\backslash F)<\varepsilon$ and $\sin^n(x)\to 0$ uniformly. Therefore, $$\int_E|\sin^n(x)|dx\leq \int_{F}|\sin^n(x)|dx+\int_{E\backslash F}dx=m(E\backslash F)+\int_{F}|\sin^n(x)|dx\underset{n\to\infty }{\longrightarrow} m(E\backslash F)<\varepsilon$$
Therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_E\sin^n(x)dx=0.$$

Do you think it work ?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the problem correctly? As pointed out in the answer, this is trivial by dominated convergence. A traditional problem that's less trivial is to find the limit of $\int_E\sin(nx)\,dx$.

Comment: What happens when $|\sin(x)|=1$?

Comment: @PhilippeMalot That set is countable, and in particular has measure $0$.

Comment: @PhilippeMalot: What do you mean ? $\int_{x\mid |\sin(x)|=1}\sin^n(x)dx=0$ anyway...

Comment: Be careful, $\sin ^n$ does not converge *uniformly* to $0$, in fact it doesn't even converge everywhere, for example the sequence $\sin^n(3\pi/2)=(-1)^n$ alternates between $1$ and $-1$. Nevertheless your argument can be adjusted as to work, since the set of "no convergence" has measure $0$.

Comment: Well, you wrote that $\sin^n(x)\to 0$ pointwise. The right term would be "almost everywhere".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a fine proof (modulo the fact that when you write pointwise, it really should be "pointwise almost everywhere"). It can be simplified significantly, though: Use the dominated convergence theorem with dominating function $\chi_E$.

It's also worth remarking that a slight reworking of your proof gives a proof of the dominated convergence theorem (on spaces of finite measure) from Egoroff's theorem; some knowledge about continuity of measures is needed to control integral over $F$, but it's not too much extra effort.